# Password security problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, passwords

A web service stores user information in a database and uses passwords for authentication. Here's how the user password storing and authentication is implemented in ruby (the actual data storage and retrieval is outside the scope of the example):

```
require 'digest'

class User

  # Use salted passwords
  PASSWORD_SALT="trustno1"

  # Stored password hash will be accessible through user.hashed_password
  attr_accessor :hashed_password

  # Authenticates user against given password and returns true
  # the password matches the stored one
  def verify_password(password)
    if hashed_password.nil? || password.nil?
      false
    else
      User.hash_password(password) == hashed_password
    end
  end

  # Changes user's password
  def change_password(new_password)
    self.hashed_password = User.hash_password(new_password.to_s)
  end

  # Hashes the input with salt
  def self.hash_password(password)
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password + PASSWORD_SALT)
  end
end
```

However, I'm told that I have problems related to password security but I couldn't find any problem.

Comment: (1) MD5 is unsuited for password hashing (its broken and too fast) (2) you should use a new random salt per password (3) You should not try to implement secure password storage on your own but use existing (verified and secure) solutions like Rails' builtin `has_secure_password` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to implement this yourself in rails, you should use [ActiveModel::SecurePassword::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html).
Your biggest problem is that you are trying to implement this by yourself. It is too easy to screw this up.